# Java Swing Password

Tags: java, swing

My this code shows no output and no error..
(it just shows applet started). please help thanks
You can run it in eclipse..whole code is included..Thank you very much for your help

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JPasswordA extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    static JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your password:");
    static JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
    static JButton enter = new JButton("Submit");
    static Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
    final static int WIDTH = 465;
    final static int HEIGHT = 150;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(passwordLabel);
        passwordLabel.setFont(bigFont);
        frame.add(input);
        frame.add(enter);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        enter.addActionListener(new Action());
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String inputPassword = input.getText();
            String passWord = "Rosebud";
            if (inputPassword.equals(passWord)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "               Your password is              correct,"
                        + "\n                     You may proceed.",
                        "Password Correct",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Sorry, you have entered an incorrect password,"
                        + "\n       Make sure your CAPS are not locked.",
                        "Password Incorrect",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the question to ask. Please ask a question that can be answered by us.

Comment: Make the class JPasswordA as abstract, kindly try the following line instead:-                                                           public abstract class JPasswordA extends JApplet implements ActionListener { ...}

Answer (score 2):

The `main` method is not invoked when a hybrid applet is run as an application. Therefore you need to add all the components in the `init` method of the `JApplet` instead. Also add the components to the applet itself and not a separate `JFrame` (Automatic popup dialogs from web pages are never popular!).

Answer (score 0):

To run the applet, create a html file like-

```
<html>
    <title>Password Applet</title>  
    <applet code="JPasswordA.class" width="465" height="150"></applet>  
</html>
```

You didn't implement the init properly. I changed the code a bit.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JPasswordA extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    private final static JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your password:");
    private final static JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
    private final static JButton enter = new JButton("Submit");
    private final static Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
    private final static int WIDTH = 465;
    private final static int HEIGHT = 150;

    public void init(){

        setVisible(true); 
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(passwordLabel);
        passwordLabel.setFont(bigFont);
        add(input);
        add(enter);
        enter.addActionListener(this);

    }             

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

        String inputPassword = input.getText();
        String passWord = "Rosebud";

        if(inputPassword.equals(passWord)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your password is correct,\nYou may proceed.", "Password Correct", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you have entered an incorrect password,\nMake sure your CAPS are not locked.", "Password Incorrect", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`frame.setVisible(true)` should be after frame.add(enter) in the main method(Applet init() if it is an applet)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, a moderator deleted my answer and didnt explain why.

Here it is AGAIN:

If you start it as a Java Application it works fine on eclipse.

You forgot to override the init method and just used main instead.

Find working code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;

public class JPasswordA extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    static JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your password:");
    static JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
    static JButton enter = new JButton("Submit");
    static Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
    final static int WIDTH = 465;
    final static int HEIGHT = 150;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setBackground(Color.red);

        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(passwordLabel);
        passwordLabel.setFont(bigFont);
        frame.add(input);
        frame.add(enter);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        enter.addActionListener(new Action());
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String inputPassword = input.getText();
            String passWord = "Rosebud";
            if (inputPassword.equals(passWord)) {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(
                                null,
                                "               Your password is               correct,\n                     You may proceed.",
                                "Password Correct", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(
                                null,
                                "Sorry, you have entered an incorrect password,\n       Make sure your CAPS are not locked.",
                                "Password Incorrect", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```